# Modifying and Existing Theme in Drupal

Tags: theming, console

The theme I am using has a slider -- a panel of automatically changing images to display a topic that the user can choose -- but it only shows a few slides.  I want to extend it to a dozen slides.  I did simple text searches to determine which files in the theme are used code files to provide the functionality to the slider.  That was the easy part.  I was able to extend the code from the few slides to 12 slides.

Now comes the more difficult and hidden part.  As I see it, each slide has two parts that are not hard coded.  First, each slide has a caption -- a text description.  Secondly, each slide has a URL associated with it that is where the browser goes if the user clicks on the slide.  These two things are not hardcoded in any of the PHP or other files, as far as I can tell.  They can be edited by the admin in the drupal backend admin settings.

So I assumed that these fields are somehow set and retained in the database.  But I did a search on a downloaded copy of the database and I did not find this text.

Please advise.  What additional work do I need to do to complete this task?

The theme is called "impact_theme" and as far as I can tell all the code for it resides in

sites\all\themes\impact_theme

The README.txt file for the theme is:

```
About Impact Theme
====================
Impact Theme is a Drupal 7 theme. The theme is not dependent on any
core theme. Its very light weight for fast loading with modern look.
  Simple and clean design
  Drupal standards compliant
  Implementation of a JS Slideshow
  Multi-level drop-down menus
  Footer with 4 regions
  A total of 10 regions
  Compatible and tested on IE7, IE8, IE9+, Opera, Firefox, Chrome browsers

Browser compatibility:
=====================
The theme has been tested on following browsers. IE7+, Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera.

Drupal compatibility:
=====================
This theme is compatible with Drupal 7.x.x

Developed by
============
www.devsaran.com

Slideshow photos by http://www.flickr.com/photos/68666702@N00/

Help and Support Us
=====================
Please consider a small donation
Paypal ID : donation@devsaran.com
```

============================================================================

I made a subtheme according to this page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/creating-a-sub-theme.

I logged in to the Administrative Dashboard and I made the subtheme as the default theme.

And then the website immediately crashed and I am unable to see anything apart from "HTTP ERROR 500".

What do you think I should do now?

For completeness sake, I will list here the screenshots I made when I was comparing my modifications to the original theme.

I am thinking what I should do now is try to step back and see if I can narrow down the point where the website crashes.  But in order to do that, I wonder if it will do any good to just modify the files.  I mean, the subtheme is already set as the default theme.  How can I undo that without being able to log into the Admin Dashboard?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are number of different slider modules, so you must provide more detailed information on how exactly slider is implemented.

Comment: I will add more information

Comment: For one, those are theme settings and would be located under that themes configuration in the admin, Admin > Apperance > Theme. Two, without knowing _what_ the 500 error is, we can't help debug it.